# How to get radio button selections into an ArrayList?

Tags: java, android, arraylist

I have an application in which I have a list of students (obtained from SQLite) and radio buttons stating whether the student is present or not. The problem is I want to get the status (present or absent) of all students in a list, as well as their names I cant seem to get anything from the list.

Here is my adapter:

```
    public class ClassAdapter extends BaseAdapter {
private Activity activity;
private LayoutInflater inflater;
private List<Student> atte;
private ClassStateAdapterListener listener;
private LayoutInflater mInflater;
private RadioGroup radioGroup;
public static ArrayList<String> selectedStates;


public ClassAdapter(Activity activity, List<Student> students,LayoutInflater inflater) {
    this.activity = activity;
    this.atte = students;
     selectedStates = new ArrayList<>();
    //selectedStates = new ArrayList<String>();
    for (int i = 0; i < atte.size(); i++) {
        selectedStates.add("error");
    }
    mInflater = inflater;
}

@Override
public int getCount() {
    return atte.size();
}

@Override
public Object getItem(int location) {
    return atte.get(location);
}

@Override
public long getItemId(int position) {
    return position;
}

@Override
public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

    if (inflater == null)
        inflater = (LayoutInflater) activity
                .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    if (convertView == null)
        convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.class_list_item, null);

    radioGroup = (RadioGroup) convertView.findViewById(R.id.test_answer_options);
    final RadioButton attePresent = (RadioButton) convertView.findViewById(R.id.rep_present);
    RadioButton atteAbsent = (RadioButton) convertView.findViewById(R.id.rep_absent);

    TextView name = (TextView_Lato) convertView.findViewById(R.id.name);
    TextView sch_id = (TextView_Lato) convertView.findViewById(R.id.schoolId);
    TextView class_name = (Textview_lato_thin) convertView.findViewById(R.id.className);
    //TextView course_name = (Textview_lato_thin) convertView.findViewById(R.id.courseName);
    //atteState = selectedAnswerOption(radioGroup.getCheckedRadioButtonId());

    final Student student = atte.get(position);

    name.setText(student.getStud_nat_id());
    sch_id.setText(student.getSName());
    class_name.setText(student.getClassname());


    attePresent.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
        @Override
        public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {
            if (isChecked && selectedStates!= null && selectedStates.size() !=0){
                selectedStates.set(position, "present");
            }
        }
    });

    atteAbsent.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
        @Override
        public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {
            if (isChecked && selectedStates!= null && selectedStates.size() !=0)
                selectedStates.set(position, "absent");

        }
    });

    return convertView;
}

public interface ClassStateAdapterListener {
    public void getState(Student attendance);
}
```

}
I have a setOnCheckedChangeListener for **EACH** (both present and absent) radio button:

```
attePresent.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
            @Override
            public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {
                // supposed to set present values in ArrayList if Present RadioButton is checked
                if (isChecked && selectedStates!= null && selectedStates.size() !=0){
                    selectedStates.set(position, "present");
                }

            }
        });
```

I also have a submit button for submitting, which for now should temporarily Toast the student list and the student state

```
submit.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                String message = "";
                // get the value of selected states from custom adapter
                for (int i = 0; i < ClassAdapter.selectedStates.size(); i++) {
                    message = message + "\n" + (i + 1) + " " + ClassAdapter.selectedStates.get(i);

                }

                Log.e("SSSSSSSSSSSSs", ClassAdapter.selectedStates.size()+"");
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), message, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
        });
```

That Log is printing:

```
10-08 18:52:51.900 9105-9105/**.**.*****.****** E/SSSSSSSSSSSSs: 0
```

But my list has 2 students at the moment. What am I missing here? Please help.

Student model class:

```
public class Student {
    private String sch_id;
    private String name;
    private String stud_nat_id;
    private String passw;
    private String email;
    private String guardian;
    private String classname;

    public Student(String sch_id, String name, String stud_nat_id, String passw, String email, String guardian, String classname) {
        this.sch_id = sch_id;
        this.name = name;
        this.stud_nat_id = stud_nat_id;
        this.passw = passw;
        this.email = email;
        this.guardian = guardian;
        this.classname = classname;
    }

    public String getSch_id() {
        return sch_id;
    }

    public void setSch_id(String sch_id) {
        this.sch_id = sch_id;
    }

    public String getSName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setSName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public String getStud_nat_id() {
        return stud_nat_id;
    }

    public void setStud_nat_id(String stud_nat_id) {
        this.stud_nat_id = stud_nat_id;
    }

    public String getPassw() {
        return passw;
    }

    public void setPassw(String passw) {
        this.passw = passw;
    }

    public String getEmail() {
        return email;
    }

    public void setEmail(String email) {
        this.email = email;
    }

    public String getGuardian() {
        return guardian;
    }

    public void setGuardian(String guardian) {
        this.guardian = guardian;
    }

    public String getClassname() {
        return classname;
    }

    public void setClassname(String classname) {
        this.classname = classname;
    }
}
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: can you post student model class and full adapter code?

Comment: @Naitik I have added requested code

Comment: Add a boolean field attendence in `Student` class. change the value of it in `onCheckedChange` and show presnet or absent based on this field.

Comment: @DheerubhaiBansal thanks, that should fix it

Comment: i am using same model but also add leave option kindly guide me how can i do it,@D.J and @Vincent H Guyo.